# I want to to retrieve the data from the table in the format

Tags: sqlite

I have the data in the table like the following.

```
column1 | column2 | column3

123       234        1234567890
123       234        1234567892
234       123        1234567893
345       234        1234567894
345       123        1234567895
```

I want the output to be in the following format

```
234  123  1234567893
345  234  1234567894
345  123  1234567895
```

can anyone tell me how write a query to retrieve the data in the above specified format..

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Why are there only three rows in the result set? Which three rows should be selected?

Comment: Neither it is clear what have you already tried or in which database engine you are doing this :)

Comment: Sorry for the not explaining properly in the above query ....i wanna to retrieve the data from the table with the unique pair of the first and second rows and if we have more than one unique pair in the table then i want to retrieve the latest record from the table...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this is what you want,

```
select b.column2,b.column1,max(b.column3) column3 from table1 a, table1 b 
where a.column1=b.column2 group by b.column2,b.column1;
```

Comment: Will the above query retrieve the unique pair of data from the table,Suppose if i have a value 'A' in the first row first column,'B' in the first row second column and the value 'B' in the second row first column,'A' in the second row second column.I want a single record from the table.

Answer (score 0):

The pairs of unique items can be found with
    SELECT column1, column2, MAX( ROWID) GROUP BY column1, column2;
ROWID is incremented at each insertion, but doesn't quite equate to latest.

The results of the first query can now be used to create the required result.

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3 FROM tbl AS t1 JOIN ( SELECT column1, column2, ROWID AS ID FROM tbl GROUP BY column1,column2) AS t2 ON t1.ROWID = t2.ID;
```